# can I change masterpage's css for an especific aspx?

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have just made a web and it was close to be published. but now my client wants to add a new page which get's the same content as my main masterpage (logo, menu a few buttoms) but changing some colours and some background img's.

My masterpage has, ofc, the:

```
    <link id="Link1" runat="server" href="~/Styles/masterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now.. insteed of making a new masterpage for just a single aspx. Is it possible to make a new page.aspx based on my current masterpage BUT telling the masterpage to use "masterPage2.css" insteed of "masterPage.css"?

Hope the question is clear enough, english not my first lenguaje, excuse me if it's not, please, and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!!.. even with my so basic VB.
I put both css out of the stylesheet, then on the master page I added:

```
<link runat="server" id="ChangingCss" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

now, at the master vb file this:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim test As String = Request.RawUrl
    If test Like "*page.aspx*" Then
        ChangingCss.Href = "~/Styles/sec.css"

    Else
        ChangingCss.Href = "~/Styles/Main.css"
    End If

End Sub
```

This may be my first vb "working" code ever :) so happy. anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, make sure to load another .css file with the changes that you want. ( It has to be loaded after the .css file for the masterpage)

Basically, you are overriding the css rules in your first .css file

for example
masterpage.css

```
#someid{
      background-color:Orange;
}
```

specificstyle.css

```
#someid{
    background-color:White;
}
```

So you should only add changes to specificstyle.css.

Masterpage

```
<link id="Link1" runat="server" href="~/Styles/masterPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Page.aspx

```
<link runat="server" href="~/Styles/specificstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Note: if the styles are not being overridden, then use the !important keyword in the css

```
#someid{
    background-color:White !important;
}
```

Comment: It's not working :( I've tried many different ways... in the stylesheet changing the order of import url(Main.css) and import url(sec.css), (always get sec css no idea why)... then puting the main and sec out of the stylsheet and using calling them:main in just master page and sec on the page.aspx... then even with !important, it just takes the main.css, not overwritten anything. Probably it will requiered to use visual basic but I have not much idea at all about it (if any) :(

Comment: if you check the resources of the page( what files are loaded ) does the second .css file should up as loaded?

Comment: it does. Anyway already solved it with a bit of VB. anyway thanks so much. so kind of you